# Unsure whether or not the following logic circuits I have created are correct

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have recently began studying logic gates and boolean expressions and have been told to label the 2 following logic circuits, as well as derive the full boolean expression for them. I have come up with the 2 following solutions, however I am quite unsure whether or not these solutions are correct.

I would appreciate if someone could confirm whether or not these are correct, and point out any possible mistakes I have made.

Thank you and apologies if any mistakes in these are ridiculously simple, as this is my first time attempting questions like this.

The boolean expression for each logic gate is labelled in red.

**Logic Circuit 1:**

Full boolean expression for circuit below: **E' . (((A . C) + B') + ((C + D)' . B))**
[image]

**Logic circuit 2:**

Full boolean expression for circuit below: **((A . B) + (A . C')) + (B . C + B' . C')**

[image]

Comment: both have errors ... have a close look at NAND and NOR gates

Comment: I'd take a look in particular at where you're placing the NOTs.

Comment: Review: De Morgan's laws